# Visit every dot with a line

Tags: algorithms

I have this problem where I want to fill every black shape with a line. Every dot of the shape needs to be visited by the line. Preferably creating the shortest line. Any idea how I can achieve this or to what algorithm to look at?

[image: Pixel shapes (enlarged the image 4x)]

I do not have any experience with algorithms so please keep it simple.

Comment: How can a line visit all dots if these dots do not lie in one line?

Comment: One line per shape. I should have said pixel instead of dot as well.

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Also, not all algorithms are simple. This is something you will have to get used to.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Ive tried to visualize my problem: https://imgur.com/a/RXSOlCo.

Comment: I've been searching and I think I can use a depth-first search for my problem.